# Partial Sum of Alternating Sequence Involving Binomial Coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I am interested in a closed form solution for the sum:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=r}^m (-1)^{k-r}{q \choose k}{k \choose {k-r}}~.
\end{equation}
Entering this into Wolfram Alpha yields:
\begin{equation}
\frac{(-1)^{m-r+1}(m-r+1)}{r-q}{q \choose {m+1}}{{m+1} \choose {m-r+1}}
\end{equation}
Would love some help with proving this. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried induction on $m$?

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ q,r,m\in\mathbb{N} $, we have for any $ k\geq r : $

\begin{aligned}\binom{q}{k}\binom{k}{k-r}=\frac{q!}{\left(q-k\right)!r!\left(k-r\right)!}&=\frac{\left(q-r\right)!}{\left(k-r\right)!\left(q-k\right)!}\times\frac{q!}{r!\left(q-r\right)!}\\&=\binom{q-r}{k-r}\binom{q}{r}\end{aligned}

Thus :

\begin{aligned} \sum_{k=r}^{m}{(-1)^{k-r}\binom{q}{k}\binom{k}{k-r}}&=\binom{q}{r}\sum_{k=r}^{m}{\left(-1\right)^{k-r}\binom{q-r}{k-r}}\\ &=\binom{q}{r}\sum_{k=0}^{m-r}{\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{q-r}{k}}\\ &=\binom{q}{r}+\binom{q}{r}\sum_{k=1}^{m-r}{\left(\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{q-r-1}{k}-\left(-1\right)^{k-1}\binom{q-r-1}{k-1}\right)}\\ &=\binom{q}{r}+\binom{q}{r}\left(\left(-1\right)^{m-r}\binom{q-r-1}{m-r}-1\right)\\ &=\left(-1\right)^{m-r}\binom{q}{r}\binom{q-r-1}{m-r} \end{aligned}

(Note that in the third line we used Pascal's triangle formula : $ \binom{q-r}{k}=\binom{q-r-1}{k}+\binom{q-r-1}{k-1} $).